# How to visualize the workflow of large functions in R

Tags: r, debugging

I would like to visualize the workflow of a large function in diagram form using R, I used a package called `flow` for this purpose, but the given diagram is so blurred and totally unreadable.

Here's a simple example for visualizing the function of interest:

```
remotes::install_github("moodymudskipper/flow")
library(flow)
library(bvarsv)
data(usmacro)
flow_run(bvar.sv.tvp(usmacro))
```

Is there any way to improve the visualization and makes it more clear? I also would like to know if there are better methods to visualize the workflows of large functions in R.